# Anylogic Empty collection error (java.util.NoSuchElementException)

Tags: anylogic

To start on i will discribe my model. I'm working on a simulation based on a last mile fleet delivery and I am using collections inside a population (vans) of agents called Van. In this collections (route) I am storing agents called orders that they have the parameters latitude and longitude of the final destination. I'm taking all the data from a DB and introducig it on a source block. On the exit of the source block the following code is implemented for adding the agents to the collection by an unique ID:

`findFirst(vans, v -> v.Key == agent.VanKey).route.addLast(agent);`

Before the last mile delivery the orders are processed by a crossdock.

For the pickup i am using a pickup block as i have a specific timestamp for the vans. When I want to assing the first delivert taking the first agent from the collection i have the following error:

**java.util.NoSuchElementException**

I notice that anylogic dont found any element in the collection but when I look inside the population of all the vans I see that the elements are in the collection.

How can i access to this elements? How can i fix this error?

I'm leaving some prints for better understanding of the problem.

[Order Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeUsd.png)

[Last Mile Delivery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERk7q.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOgvc.png)

[van agent from simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G3Pf.png)

[Van Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEkOw.png)

[PickupFromOffice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gk3r.png)

[vans Population](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s6LI.png)

I read library of collection in anylogic and lots of posts of stackoverflow

Comment: Not sure about the issue, but the code is a bit redundant, `findFirst(vans, v -> v.Key == agent.VanKey).route.addLast(agent);` has the same funcionality and is more readable. (Also I suggest conforming to Java naming conventions and starting your variables with lower case letters.) Are you sure that the van exists already when the order is created? The error does not say that the collection is empty but that it couldn't find and element which satisfies the condition `v.Key == agent.VanKey`.

Comment: Hi @mczandrea thanks for the correction about the code, I'm still learning Java since I am use to code in python only. When the order is created I can see that my population of vans are created but they are not inside the blocks of the process. The vans enter the process with a source block which is linked to a database by a specific date. I will keep up with your last recomendation but anyways if I print a log with the collection size it cannot find any element (Traceln(agent.route.size()))

Comment: Can you post more screenshots of the model? Where do you call this traceln and why? Are you sure this `findFirst` function is the one that throws an error? Based on your error screenshot, I think the problem is with your `pickupFromOffice` block. If you check error message in the console, there will be blue links that bring you to the lines that threw the error. (Also I'm confused about your process flow. Source block creates new agents, if you need to send existing agents into the processes you need to use an Enter block. )

Comment: I think you might be right! I will try to do it by an enter block. Anyways I'm updating the post with more info. I am creating the agents with a database as regards the population and the source, but I think they are not the same agents. Is there any way to create the same agents as the population I already got?

Comment: You cannot "create the same agent". A new agent will be a new agent, it might have the same parameters but it would be a different object. Either create an empty `vans` population and create the agents in it with your Source ('add agents to custom population' setting), or create the population beforehand and send the agents to an Enter block. Please share a screenshot of your vans population to show how it is set up.

Comment: Ok now I undestand how it works, thanks for that! I will update the question with the last screenshot you asked me of the `vans` population, but remember they must enter the block at the specific timestamp I have in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the agents from the source of the last mile delivery where not the same agents as the population which have the collections fullfield inside.